# Is $g$ surjective or not? If yes, then why?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Is $g:R\rightarrow R$ a surjective function if $g(2xy+g(x))+g(g(y)g(x)+x)=g(2xg(y)+g(x))+g(yg(x)+x)$.

The problem was given by my friend but I am unable to make any progress except trying to work on few substitutions such as $y=\frac{(y-1)g(x)}{2x}+1$.

Comment: What does the question mark in the middle of your functional equation mean?

Comment: Isn't $g=0$ a solution?

Comment: Or any other constant function.  (I'm assuming that the random question mark shouldn't be there)

Comment: Apologies, the question mark was a typo.